# How to pass the variable to ssh command on shell

Tags: linux, ssh

I am writing the script to ssh the server.

I have the server which require the verification code and password login, and I want the script can login the server and run some script on server every day (crontab).

I only have the access on the server and I cannot the right to setup the crontab on the server.
So i want to setup the crontab and script on my own server to do.

(If i cannot run the script on server, at least I want to login my server via one line command.)

**Currnet Flow**

```
user ~% ssh xxxx@example.com

The authenticity of host 'example.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256?[yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? (yes)
Verification code:  (input)
Password: (input)

xxxx$ ./a.sh
```

I write the command below

`print "(verification code)\n(pwd)\n" | ssh -t -t xxxx@example.com`

I think that this command will pass "*the code* , enter, *the password*" to the ssh and perform the one line command login.

However the output is

```
Verification code: | (cursor)
```

Any one can help me how to fix this (let the script auto press enter) ??

Answer (score 0):

Use 'sshpass', for example:

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh <username>@<remote-address> ./a.sh
```

Comment: I am not familiar with sshpass, but I suppose the example you provided wouldn't be sufficient because apparently a "verification code" is needed in addition to the password.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't have an answer if "verification code and password login" is the only authentication option setup in the server.

Since you have not mention key based authentication in your question, I would suggest investigating whether it is an option.

Use this to generate private/public keys for the machine sending the command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

That would normally create the keys in ~/.ssh (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub).

Then, use this to authorise login on the server:

```
ssh-copy-id xxxx@example.com
```

That would add your public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in the server.